# User having two foregin keys?

Tags: php, laravel, database-design

region, zone, district tables are all populated. User can get region, zone and district id from form each for temporary address and permanent address. What would be best database design for this:

Currently i am thinking of:

**users table:**

```
id  name  email  region_id  zone_id  district_id  tregion_id  tzone_id  tdistrict_id
```

but how can i make relation? 1 user can have 2 regions each for temporary address and permanent address? Even if i setup hasMany relations, wouldn't there be two foreign keys
 in terms of `region_id` and `tregion_id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having two different foreign keys to the same table is perfectly fine. in the model you can have two relations where you define the different keys:

```
public function region(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Region::class, 'region_id');
}
public function tempRegion(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Region::class, 'tregion_id');
}
```

Comment: oh. Isn't region hasMany relation with user instead?  because i don't have user_id in region table. instead have region_id in users table?

Answer (score 0):

You should go at least till 3NF for your database design and then you may not need to maintain different fields for Temporary and Permanent. Also to avoid redundancy like in case of multiple persons stays at same address then same address will be repeating.

Your design may alike;

```
1. User Table (id, name, email)
2. Address Table (id, region_id,zone_id,district_id)
```

To store two or more (future proof) numbers of user address (***one to many***), you will be needed a table for user-address assignment say UserAddress, this will look like as per following; Add an address identifier field say `AddressType`.

```
3. UserAddress(   
    Id, UserId (FK to User), AddressId (FK to Address Table), 
    AddressType (Permanent/Temporary))
```

**Future Scope Improvement with least changes**

Now you also have opportunity to maintain the dates, for which period a user has stayed in which address, in this case user address table will needs two more fields.

`Id, UserId (FK to User), AddressId (FK to Address Table), AddressType, startDate, endDate, IsCurrent, IsRented` and `other desirable attributes` ...

If will add one more field to UserTable table say IsCurrent, then you can directly query the user current address by simple `AND condition`;

```
 AND IsCurrent=1;
```

Comment: and what is that isTemporary for?

Comment: I don't require n addresses. only 2 and both are compulsory. now isTemporary doesnot make sense? or i am not understanding?

Comment: Then change the name, make it AddressType.

Comment: I answered this question towards database-design tag.